# Blazor Server .SetDefaultCulture() not working with all browsers when hosted in IIS10

Tags: c#, localization, blazor-server-side, iis-10, .net-5

**My goal**

I want to seperate the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture initialisation.
The application uses one currency standard, but can show multiple text translations for different users (based on .resx files).

**My code**

I use the following code in Startup.Configure to achieve this.

```
 var configuredCulture = "da-DK";
        var supportedUICultures = new[] { "en", "nl" };
        var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions()
            .SetDefaultCulture(configuredCulture)
            .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedUICultures);
        app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
```

**configuredCulture is normally read from AppSettings.json so it can be set by the appliation administrator.*

**My problem**

The code above works as expected on my development machine (using IIS Express whitin Visual Studio) for Chromium Edge, Chrome & FireFox. Text translations are based on browser language and currrency is read from appSettings.config (or in this case hard-coded).

After publishing the application to Server 2019 running IIS10, *FireFox* and *Chrome* always show a dollar sign, so I asume they convert the CurrentCulture to en-US.
*Chromium Edge* & *Safari on Iphone* shows me the right value (in this case 2,95 kr.) so they do work as exptected.

**My question**

Is my culture configuration setup the right way? In other words do i need to make changes in code or should I look at the IIS configuration? (Allthough i didn't find localisation settings in IIS10).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that FireFox and Chrome require the set Culture to be included in the UICulture list. I thought these where seperate things.
So changing:

```
var supportedUICultures = new[] { "en", "nl" };
```

into:

```
var supportedUICultures = new[] { "en", "nl", "da-DK" };
```

fixed the issue for all browsers.